# Date select : default year selected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On form 1, I have a `formtastic` date_select field.

```
= f.input :date_from, :discard_day   => true, 
                      :discard_month => true,
                      :order         => [:year], 
                      :start_year    => 1950, 
                      :end_year      => Date.today.year, 
                      :include_blank => false
```

When the form is rendered, the `year` drop down box defaults to 1950.

On form 2, I have another `formtastic` date_select field.

```
= f.input :date_from, :discard_day   => true, 
                      :order         => [:month, :year], 
                      :start_year    => 1950, 
                      :end_year      => Date.today.year, 
                      :include_blank => false
```

When the form is rendered, the `year` drop down box defaults to 2000.

How do you explain this behavior? Ideally, I want the year field to default to `10 years ago`.

P.S:
Setting default value made no difference.

```
:default       => Date.today
```

Comment: both code are executing perfectly and are defaulting to the year 1950. I woud like to know what are you expecting exactly and please elaborate the problem.

Comment: I want the year to default to a current year - 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
:selected => Date.today.year - 10
```

Looking at the RDoc for formtastic, that should work: http://rdoc.info/github/justinfrench/formtastic/master/Formtastic/SemanticFormBuilder:date_input